# gitignore by file size?

Tags: git, configuration, blob, gitignore, large-files

I'm trying to implement Git to manage creative assets (Photoshop, Illustrator, Maya, etc.), and I'd like to exclude files from Git based on file size rather than extension, location, etc.

For example, I don't want to exclude all .avi files, but there are a handful of massive +1GB avi files in random directories that I don't want to commit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would warn that Git is known to have poor performance with large, binary files, and this problem is only now slowly being resolved.  I would recommend against using Git for things besides plain text.

Comment: @erjiang: Agreed. (except small binary files are perfectly fine; sure, they can't be prettily diffed, but no VCS can do that) Of course, the OP is saying that he explicitly does not want to track large files, so it might be all okay!

Comment: There's certainly no built-in way to do this. You could sort of implement it by adding a pre-commit hook which checks the size of all files to be committed, and aborts if any are over the threshold. You could add additional automation, but be careful. The last thing you want is to lose data by accidentally ignoring important content. (In order of increasing danger, you could: automatically unstage the large files, automatically add them to the gitignore, and even proceed with the modified commit instead of aborting.)

Comment: There's been some talk on the git ML recently about extending the .gitignore syntax, and one of the proposals is to allow .gitignore to delegate to an external tool to make decisions about what is and is not ignored. It sounds like this would be perfect for what you want. Unfortunately it's just a proposal for now, but this may show up eventually.

Comment: What is the point of controlling those files? Certainly, just saving them under a different name and even adding a small description in the name, or in a different text file will be more cost efficient and (in case of larger files) time efficient. I see no advantages of keeping track of avi files.

Comment: @KevinBallard can you provide a link to the discussion?

Comment: @JonasStein: That comment is almost 4 years old. I don't even remember it anymore.

Comment: To anyone arriving here, please see my updated (2020-05) answer. Git-LFS is probably the tool to use in scenarios like the one described in the original post.

Comment: the best answer for it is over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547007/11472644

Comment: the best answer for it is over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547007/11472644

Answer (score 82):

I'm new to .gitignore, so there may be better ways to do this, but I've been excluding files by file size using:

```
find . -size +1G | cat >> .gitignore
```

Obviously you'll have to run this code frequently if you're generating a lot of large files.

Comment: This is a great way to control `wp-content/uploads` folder when deploying large sites built in WordPress. Thanks for this.

Comment: I found I needed to remove the leading `./` from the start of each file before gitignore would work

Comment: This is a very old thread, but in case someone stumbled upon it and needed a pastable solution: `find . -size +1G | sed 's|^\./||g' | cat >> .gitignore`

Comment: To avoid storing duplicate file names: `find . -size +1G | sed 's|^\./||g' | cat >> .gitignore; awk '!NF || !seen[$0]++' .gitignore`. `sed` will get rid of trailing `./`, and `awk` will remove all duplicate lines ignoring empty ones by checking the number of fields present in a line (`NF`) - this is useful if your `.gitignore` is organized in sections separated by empty lines.

Comment: You all win a "useless use of cat award".

Comment: @SamWatkins do you have an example of how the above could be done without using `cat`? ( i think that it can just be completely dropped from the above? )

Comment: lol, took me a second to realize what is the cat award:
`find . -size +1G | sed 's|^\./||g' >> .gitignore`

Comment: You don't need `sed` either ... `find . -size +1G -printf '%P\n'` works too.

Comment: Can I do this in some kind of automated way? I mean something like putting a function in my repo (or in my gitignore if this possbile) that continously collects files larger than some size and puts them in the gitignore?

Comment: @RobinKohrs I have added yet another answer using a githook to add some automatic behavior

Answer (score 15):

To satisfy github's <100MB file limit, run this:

```sh
find . -size +100M | cat >> .gitignore
```

Comment: In windows, run the same command and it might add `./` to the start of each path as below

`./android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-universal-debug.apk` . 

Removing the `./` as below solved my issue; 
`android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-universal-debug.apk`

Answer (score 13):

Although the file size is very large and the following should not be an issue at all and provided that @abendine answer is correct, according to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22057427/6466510

```
find * -size +1G | cat >> .gitignore
```

it would be far better. Have a look at this too: [Difference between find . and find * in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578534/difference-between-find-and-find-in-unix/62292764#62292764) it turns out that replacing `.` with `*` here above, avoid to find things in `.git` directory.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to also offer a Windows version of this as well.

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /q /c if @fsize GTR 1073741824 echo @relpath" >> .gitignore
```

Answer (score 6):

(Update 2020-05)

Microsoft released time ago Git-LFS as Open-Source. Probably this is what most people really are searching for:

https://git-lfs.github.com/
C&P from the project page:
"Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise."

Comment: yes they shoud install git lfs and track the big files to automatic exclude them from the repositorys.

Answer (score 5):

I want to add to all these answers that you can also just use a git hook to have something more automatic (or less human-error prone) like this:

`cat .git/hooks/pre-commit`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "automatically ignoring large files"
find . -size 5M | sed 's|^\./||g' >> .gitignore
cat .gitignore | sort | uniq > .gitignore

git diff --exit-code .gitignore
exit_status=$?
if [ $exit_status -eq 1 ]
then
    set +e
    for i in `cat .gitignore`
    do
    set +e
        git rm --cached $i
    done

    git add .gitignore
    git commit .gitignore --no-verify -m"ignoring large files"

    echo "ignored new large files"
fi
```

It is pretty brute force and the downside is that in case there were new large files added by the git hook, the origin commit fails because the state (hash) changed. So you need to execute another commit to actually commit what you have staged. Consider this as a feature telling you that new large files were detected ;-)

Comment: the best answer for it is over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547007/11472644

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an answer that summarizes the suggestions about
"remove the leading ./"
and
"useless use of sed"
and
"useless use of cat"

```
find . -size +100M -printf '%P\n' >> .gitignore
```

fwiw i think that cat is fine :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this user-friendly script in python for limiting the repo size, notice that it will delete the `.gitignore` and rebuild it based on the amount of megabytes you input, supports floats.

It will automatically ignore any file path that includes `.git` in it.

Optionally, you can set it to a specific file type, search for `#specific:` and enable that piece of code to do that.

**Only tested on windows**, create `Limit Repo Size.cmd` at the root of the repo:

```
@echo off
del .gitignore
py auto-gitignore-limit-repo-file-size.py
pause
```

and then create `auto-gitignore-limit-repo-file-size.py`:

```
# Inspired by: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github
# Made by myself, feel free to use it, please put some credits for github.com/burgil somewhere if you use it

import os

def is_file_large(file_path, threshold):
    """
    Check if a file is larger than the specified threshold size.
    """
    return os.path.getsize(file_path) > threshold

def ignore_large_files(root_dir, threshold):
    """
    Ignore files larger than the specified threshold size.
    """
    total_repo_size = 0
    ignored_size = 0
    ignored_files = 0
    total_files = 0
    for root, _, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            if '.git' not in file_path: #specific: and '.json' in file_path:
                if is_file_large(file_path, threshold):
                        print(f"Ignoring {file_path}")
                        ignored_files = ignored_files + 1
                        with open(".gitignore", "a") as gitignore:
                            gitignore.write(f"# Ignored file: {os.path.relpath(file_path, start=root_dir).replace('\\', '/')}, Size: {format_file_size(os.path.getsize(file_path))}\n")
                            gitignore.write(f"{os.path.relpath(file_path, start=root_dir).replace('\\', '/')}\n")
                        ignored_size += os.path.getsize(file_path)
                else:
                    total_files = total_files + 1
                    total_repo_size += os.path.getsize(file_path)

    return total_repo_size, ignored_size, ignored_files, total_files

def format_file_size(size):
    """
    Format file size to KB, MB, GB, TB.
    """
    if size < 1024:
        return f"{size} bytes"
    elif size < 1024 * 1024:
        return f"{size / 1024:.2f} KB"
    elif size < 1024 * 1024 * 1024:
        return f"{size / (1024 * 1024):.2f} MB"
    elif size < 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024:
        return f"{size / (1024 * 1024 * 1024):.2f} GB"
    else:
        return f"{size / (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024):.2f} TB"

def get_valid_number(prompt, lower_limit, upper_limit):
    """
    Prompt the user to enter a number within the specified range.
    """
    while True:
        try:
            number = float(input(prompt))
            if number < lower_limit or number > upper_limit:
                print(f"Number must be between {lower_limit} and {upper_limit}")
            else:
                return number
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root_directory = "."
    megabytes_limit = get_valid_number("Enter the megabytes limit: ", 1, float('inf'))
    size_threshold = megabytes_limit * 1024 * 1024

    total_repo_size, ignored_size, ignored_files, total_files = ignore_large_files(root_directory, size_threshold)
    total_repo_size_formatted = format_file_size(total_repo_size)
    ignored_size_formatted = format_file_size(ignored_size)
    all_files_formatted = format_file_size(total_repo_size+ignored_size)

    print(f"\n\n\n\nIgnored files larger than {str(megabytes_limit)}MB:")
    print(f"# Total repository size: {total_repo_size_formatted}")
    print(f"# Ignored size: {ignored_size_formatted}")
    print(f"# All files size: {all_files_formatted}")
    print(f"# Ignored files count: {ignored_files}")
    print(f"# Total files in repository: {total_files}")
    print(f"# All files count: {total_files+ignored_files}\n\n\n\n")
    existing_content = ""
    if os.path.exists(".gitignore"):
        with open(".gitignore", "r") as f:
            existing_content = f.read()
    with open(".gitignore", "w") as gitignore:
        gitignore.write(f"# Ignored files larger than {str(megabytes_limit)}MB:\n")
        gitignore.write(f"# Total repository size: {total_repo_size_formatted}\n")
        gitignore.write(f"# Ignored size: {ignored_size_formatted}\n")
        gitignore.write(f"# All files size: {all_files_formatted}\n")
        gitignore.write(f"# Ignored files count: {ignored_files}\n")
        gitignore.write(f"# Total files in repository: {total_files}\n")
        gitignore.write(f"# All files count: {total_files+ignored_files}\n")
        gitignore.write("\n")
        gitignore.write(existing_content)
```

Double click `Limit Repo Size.cmd` (user-friendly)

Example output:

```
# Ignored files larger than 14.71MB:
# Total repository size: 998.69 MB
# Ignored size: 3.17 GB
# All files size: 4.15 GB
# Ignored files count: 99
# Total files in repository: 108
# All files count: 207

# Ignored file: AIChip/AI Chip - 512x512 - Wires_AI Chip - 512x512 - Wires.json, Size: 78.64 MB
AIChip/AI Chip - 512x512 - Wires_AI Chip - 512x512 - Wires.json
# Ignored file: AIChip/AI Chip Holder_AI Chip Holder.json, Size: 91.74 MB
AIChip/AI Chip Holder_AI Chip Holder.json
# Ignored file: AIChip/AI Chip - 1024x1024 - Wires_AI Chip - 1024x1024 - Wires.json, Size: 202.63 MB
AIChip/AI Chip - 1024x1024 - Wires_AI Chip - 1024x1024 - Wires.json
# Ignored file: AIChip/AIChip Landscape_AIChip Landscape.json, Size: 281.55 MB
AIChip/AIChip Landscape_AIChip Landscape.json
# Ignored file: AIChip/AIChip Portrait_AIChip Portrait.json, Size: 288.08 MB
AIChip/AIChip Portrait_AIChip Portrait.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Full_49.json, Size: 21.18 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Full_49.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Full_50.json, Size: 33.09 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Full_50.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_15.json, Size: 24.88 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_15.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_18.json, Size: 19.29 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_18.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_2.json, Size: 22.02 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_2.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_20.json, Size: 23.92 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_20.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_22.json, Size: 20.69 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_22.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_23.json, Size: 20.38 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_23.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_24.json, Size: 20.49 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_24.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_3.json, Size: 34.57 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_3.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_30.json, Size: 25.29 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_30.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_31.json, Size: 15.65 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_31.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_32.json, Size: 15.39 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_32.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_36.json, Size: 27.18 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_36.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_37.json, Size: 26.55 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_37.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_39.json, Size: 25.57 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_39.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_43.json, Size: 17.33 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_43.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_44.json, Size: 31.58 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_44.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_46.json, Size: 29.39 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_46.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_47.json, Size: 32.59 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_47.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_48.json, Size: 14.92 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_48.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_5.json, Size: 46.89 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Black/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Black_5.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_12.json, Size: 15.38 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_12.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_14.json, Size: 14.95 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_14.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_15.json, Size: 29.37 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_15.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_18.json, Size: 21.33 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_18.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_2.json, Size: 22.52 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_2.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_20.json, Size: 25.01 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_20.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_22.json, Size: 22.93 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_22.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_23.json, Size: 22.52 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_23.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_24.json, Size: 22.51 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_24.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_25.json, Size: 17.25 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_25.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_29.json, Size: 14.75 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_29.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_3.json, Size: 33.04 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_3.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_30.json, Size: 26.14 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_30.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_31.json, Size: 16.22 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_31.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_32.json, Size: 16.06 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_32.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_36.json, Size: 27.50 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_36.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_37.json, Size: 27.86 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_37.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_39.json, Size: 26.42 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_39.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_43.json, Size: 18.78 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_43.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_44.json, Size: 35.40 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_44.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_46.json, Size: 30.34 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_46.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_47.json, Size: 37.67 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_47.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_48.json, Size: 14.92 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_48.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_5.json, Size: 45.86 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Green/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Green_5.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_12.json, Size: 15.04 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_12.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_14.json, Size: 14.71 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_14.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_15.json, Size: 27.50 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_15.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_18.json, Size: 21.11 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_18.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_2.json, Size: 22.73 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_2.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_20.json, Size: 24.90 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_20.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_22.json, Size: 22.47 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_22.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_23.json, Size: 22.10 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_23.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_24.json, Size: 22.27 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_24.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_25.json, Size: 17.45 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_25.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_29.json, Size: 14.86 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_29.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_3.json, Size: 32.56 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_3.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_30.json, Size: 25.65 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_30.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_31.json, Size: 16.10 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_31.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_32.json, Size: 16.25 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_32.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_36.json, Size: 28.27 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_36.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_37.json, Size: 28.14 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_37.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_39.json, Size: 26.18 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_39.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_43.json, Size: 19.53 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_43.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_44.json, Size: 35.07 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_44.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_46.json, Size: 30.43 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_46.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_47.json, Size: 35.83 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_47.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_48.json, Size: 14.91 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_48.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_5.json, Size: 45.46 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/Red/Energy Balls - 256x256 - Red_5.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_12.json, Size: 15.40 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_12.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_14.json, Size: 14.94 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_14.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_15.json, Size: 29.68 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_15.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_18.json, Size: 21.17 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_18.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_2.json, Size: 22.55 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_2.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_20.json, Size: 24.67 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_20.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_22.json, Size: 23.16 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_22.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_23.json, Size: 22.49 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_23.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_24.json, Size: 22.69 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_24.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_25.json, Size: 17.28 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_25.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_29.json, Size: 14.73 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_29.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_3.json, Size: 33.80 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_3.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_30.json, Size: 28.02 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_30.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_31.json, Size: 15.96 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_31.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_32.json, Size: 16.04 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_32.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_36.json, Size: 29.51 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_36.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_37.json, Size: 30.19 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_37.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_39.json, Size: 27.47 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_39.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_43.json, Size: 18.05 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_43.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_44.json, Size: 34.22 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_44.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_46.json, Size: 31.02 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_46.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_47.json, Size: 40.01 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_47.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_48.json, Size: 14.92 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_48.json
# Ignored file: Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_5.json, Size: 46.24 MB
Energy Balls - 256x256/White/Energy Balls - 256x256 - White_5.json
```