# Git -- add all files that are smaller than X megabytes

Tags: git

I'm using  git to manage a non-coding-project folder that has some large files scattered all over the place.

I'm not interesting in moving the files around as they are not mine, but I know git has issues with very large files (in Linus's words, "we suck at it") and I'd like to avoid those performance issues as much as I can. So here I am, just ran `git init` and about to hit enter on `git add -A` but stop just before I do.

I'd like to try to add a flag to `git add` that selects only certain files. I'm not wanting to be prejudiced based on extension, only based on size. Can `add` or my `.gitignore` file do that?

Comment: You should also consider what to do when a file you have already added becomes "too big."

Comment: the best answer for it is over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547007/11472644

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no flags to `git` that will do what you want.  However, there are a lot of other utilities available that would work just fine...such as the `find` command.  To add all files smaller than 4 MB:

```
find * -size -4M -type f -print | xargs git add
```

This assumes that you have no filenames containing spaces (e.g., "my important file").  If you have such files, then:

```
find * -size -4M -type f -print0 | xargs -0 git add
```

**UPDATE**: Note that I've replaced `.` with `*` here, because otherwise it will find (and try to add) things in your `.git` directory, which is not helpful.

Comment: huh, just curious, what would I use (in the place of `git add` I guess) to count the number of files found matching a minimum size number?

Comment: To add dot files that are not dot-git files, you can complextificatify the `find` with stuff like `find . -name .git -prune -o ...`, but usually this is not worthwhile unless you're writing a real script.

Comment: For the version of the command with `-print`, you can just pipe the output of `find` to `wc -l` (to count lines).

Comment: apparently you can use the -X option to do the same thing as the `print0` & `-0` thing, according to `man find`

Answer (score 14):

Building off of larsks's answer, you could do the opposite to add the large files to your `.gitignore`

```
echo "# Files over 4mb" >> .gitignore
find * -size +4M -type f -print >> .gitignore
```