# Difference between find . and find * in unix

Tags: unix

What is the difference between find . vs find * .

When i am trying to search for a file in current directory i.e. which was modified not more than 20 days ,i fired below query

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -mtime -20
```

The above command gives no output but

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -mtime -20
```

gives me the output that is required.Why is this happening i am searching in current directory only and . also means current directory

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @ignacio is correctly saying, you should also take into account that:

- `find .` looks for hidden files too, e.g. into the `.git` if there's one
- `find *` looks for the visible contents only within the directory

Have a look at this answer update too, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22057427/6466510

Answer (score 2):

`.` means "start with the current directory". A depth of 0 can only be `.`.

`*` means "start with the visible contents of the directory". A depth of 0 will be each of the visible items in the directory.